# How to control serially correlated independent variables?

Tags: regression, time-series, autocorrelation, multicollinearity

I'm interested in studying the impact of one variable (e.g., R&D expense at year T) on future firm performance (e.g., Sales in year T+5), I know it's incorrect to specify the following model:

*Sales_(T+5) = f (R&D_T, R&D_(T+1), R&D_(T+2), R&D_(T+3), R&D_(T+4))*

However, I was wondering is there any ways to also control for strongly correlated independent variables such as R&D_(T+1), R&D_(T+2), R&D_(T+3), R&D_(T+4) in the same model?

Please help! Thanks

Comment: What do you think of my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a VAR model for the two variables and study the effect of one variable on another using impulse response functions, forecast error variance decomposition and Granger causality. For example, the simplest VAR(1) model for two variables would be
\begin{aligned}
x_t &= \theta_{10} + \theta_{11} x_{t-1} + \theta_{12} y_{t-1} + \varepsilon_{2,t}, \\
y_t &= \theta_{20} + \theta_{21} x_{t-1} + \theta_{22} y_{t-1} + \varepsilon_{2,t}.
\end{aligned}
The VAR model accounts for the autocorrelated nature of the data by including lags of both the dependent and the independent variable. You may also have higher lag order, include exogenous variables, seasonal dummies, etc. The model can be estimated using equation-by-equation OLS, for example. There is an R package for VAR models; it is ["vars"](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjL36qrjNvSAhUlIsAKHT-1AxsQFggqMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcran.r-project.org%2Fpackage%3Dvars&usg=AFQjCNHh-7pN6o53ZShLks6mrRaGaobD4g&sig2=mWgRGTZtfQ1lBVBLnhZKiw).